# Inject CDI Session Bean in Servlet

Tags: servlets, cdi, jboss-weld

I'm getting in my project inject (@ Inject) CDI Beans scopes Request and Session in a servlet. The problem is that for session beans CDI I'm not getting that states remain. I try to modify the state of the bean from my servlet but when I try to recover from a page is as if the servlet had failed to change state.
Someone could help me?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to help you with so few information. Could you post code and configuration ?

Regarding CDI and Servlet, you also should have a look to [Seam Servlet module](http://www.seamframework.org/Seam3/ServletModule), it could help you to achieve tour needs differently